# Base64: How to show image in IE7? (ASP.net/VB.net)

Tags: internet-explorer-7, base64, captcha

I'm generating captchas in ASP.net/VB.
Everything is working well except in IE 7.

I need to display my captchas in IE7.

How can I do that?
My `img src` starts with `data:image/png;base64,`.

Is there a way with jQuery and a little bit VB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) to work around the problem for IE 7.

An explanation and example is available at [MHTML – when you need data: URIs in IE7 and under](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/).